SLAM Toolbox with hilly terreins
is it possible to map hilly terrains with SLAM Toolbox, 2D LiDAR, IMU and the odometry provider by the robot itself? Or do I need to search for another algorithm? Or for mapping 3D environments I need a 3D LiDAR?
I currently use ROS2 Humble + RPLiDAR a3 and HWT9073 IMU.
Thanks
Edit: Thanks to S. Macenski I have the confirmation that SLAM Toolbox just works with 2D environments.
